# Downloading a Github Library to my Python to Extract XBRL Data

Tags: python, github, installation, repository, github-for-windows

I know this is a dumb question but I am not following the instructions on how to install and use this library on Github (https://github.com/catalyst-cooperative/ferc-xbrl-extractor) and use this package to extract data from the ferc6-xbrl-2022.zip file into a local .sqlite file i will house on my desktop. Can anyone assist me with this? Thank you!